# Getting a question unlocked.

Tags: discussion, locked-posts

One of my questions has been locked while dispute about it's content is being resolved. This makes me unable to place a bounty on my question. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Just to give context to save others the effort of looking, it seems like the question regards [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747354/), which was presumably locked because the [OP added, then removed a tag 10 times](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1747354/revisions).

Comment: Right: The post says  Notice added Content dispute by Daniel Fischer♦   - And for more information, to visit Meta.

Comment: If I may ask, why add 9 times and remove 9 times the same tag?

Comment: To try and attract more view to the thread. Instead, I was advised to place a bounty, which is what I would like to do now.

Comment: And your apparent tendency to try and abuse the system for getting attention, I think that a cool-down period is a good idea.

Comment: "To try and attract more view to the thread". So you're saying your post deserved to be locked? Case closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How do I go about doing this?

You wait until the question is unlocked, then you place the bounty. The lock in such a case will typically be such that it expires automatically after some time or will be lifted by a moderator.

Note that at the very moment you could not place the bounty anyway, as the question needs to be at least two days old to place a bounty on it.

Comment: How long does this normally take??

Comment: Up to a week; I'd guess in this case it will not be a full week. Yet I'd further guess it will depend on how you behave in the interim.